# NSView height direction with flipped drawing coordinates

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nsrect, nstrackingarea, cgsize

I subclassed a custom view which I dragged into a window in Interface Builder. As the mouse enters the bounds of the view, I would like the height of the view to change. My problem is the height change is upwards and not downwards. I tried flipping the coordinates of the view with `(BOOL)isFlipped` but it doesn't have any effect on the direction of the height change. Any help on how I can change the height in the downward direction?

```
#import "ViewA.h"

@implementation ViewA

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                                    options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited|NSTrackingActiveAlways)
                                                                      owner:self
                                                                   userInfo:nil];
        [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor redColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}

- (BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}


- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSRect rect = self.frame;
    rect.size.height = 120;
    self.frame = rect;
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSRect rect = self.frame;
    rect.size.height = 90;
    self.frame = rect;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the co-ordinate system in Cocoa starts from the bottom left corner. i.e the co-ordinates `(0,0)` is at the bottom left corner of the screen/parent view. So the increment in y co-ordinate (height) would increase the size upwards. What you should do is as you increment the height, shift the origin downwards, For e.g. if you want to increase/decrease the frame height to 90;

```
CGFloat heightDiff = 90 -self.frame.size.height;

NSRect  rect = self.frame;

rect.size.height = 90;

rect.origin.y -= heightDiff;

self.frame = rect;
```

That should do it.

Override the parent view's `isFlipped` and not the method of the view itself for the expected behavior.

For instance if you are adding it to the content view of `window`, sub class the windows `contentView` and override its `isFlipped` method to return `YES`.

Comment: But I implemented the isFlipped method to flip the coordinate system to the top left.

Comment: The `isFlipped` method is not for setting directly. You override the method in subclasses so that it returns YES if you are using a flipped co-ordinate system. Just setting `isFlipped` to YES won't flip the co-ordinate system.

Comment: @Gavin: oops. missed that completely.Only gave it a cursory glance. Made a fool of myself didn't I. :) It should have worked. Anyway did you try the first solution?

Comment: @Gavin: Wait a minute. Overriding the `isFlipped` method of this view won't change anything.It has to be done on the parent view so that the height changes the way you want. By overriding this only the drawing/subviews inside `ViewA` will behave the way you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26907/discussion-between-rakesh-and-gavin)

Comment: Got it. Using `isFlipped` for the `contentView` instead of the `view` works fine. So the parent view must be the one where you flip the coordinate system. Thanks.